# How to disable sudo privileges to a user in Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, sudo, sshd

I have created an ssh key-based user in my server. I want to disable all sudo privileges to that particular user.

I have done the following;

```
sudo deluser user sudo

/usr/sbin/deluser: The user is not a member of group `sudo'.
```

and

```
sudo gpasswd -d user sudo

Removing the user from group sudo
gpasswd: the user is not a member of 'sudo'
```

After that, I checked `sudo -l -U user`

```
User  may run the following commands on the server:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Does this mean, he can still do sudo su? how to remove complete sudo privileges to the user.

I don't want anyone to do sudo su also apart from me

EDIT:

@Melebius, The snippet in `/etc/sudoers`

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

EDIT 02:

Is there a different way to disable sudo privileges for users created using SSH Key? Somewhere in sshd_config?

Comment: Thanks, @Melebius I have edited my question and included the outputs also

Comment: Thanks for the update. Have you also checked the `admin` group? Check also your `/etc/sudoers` file and files in `/etc/sudoers.d` (if any) to see the rules which might allow other users/groups to run `sudo`.

Comment: It's possible that the `User` gets their rights as an individual the same way that `root` does (`sudoers` line beginning with the username) rather than a group membership (`sudoers` lines beginning with `%`)

Comment: Thanks, @steeldriver How can I check that? How to disable sudo privileges to users in that case?

Comment: if you don't want to allow certain group to allow sudo put a `#` before sudo in *sudoers* file like this `# %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

Comment: @SidtheGooner you would need to search /etc/sudoers **and** any files in /etc/sudoers.d for an entry containing the username, then remove or comment it out using `visudo`